# Why is my custom attribute not displaying on the order confirmation?

Tags: magento2.2.6

I am trying to display the alternate part number on my order confirmation.

I copied the items.phtml to  example/example/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml and added the code

```
 <th class="item-qty">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('AlternatePartNumber') ?>
        </th>
```

This heading displays properly on the order confirmation.

I took default.phtml and copied it to example/example/Magento_sales/templates/email/default.phtml

I added the code

```
 <td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAlternatePartNumber($_item) ?></td>
```

After Price so it now looks like-

```
<td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?></td>
<td class="item-price"><?=  /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?></td>
<td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAlternatePartNumber($_item) ?></td>
```

It still will not display. How can I get the alternate part number to display?

Edit: Entire default.phtml

```
<?php
 /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_order = $_item->getOrder();
?>
<tr>
<td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>">
    <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
    <p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU') ?>: <?= 
$block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
    <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
        <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
            <dt><strong><em><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  
$option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
            <dd>
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  nl2br($option['value']) ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
    <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
        <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
</td>

<td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?></td>
<td class="item-price"><?=  /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?></td>
<td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAlternatePartNumber($_item) ?></td>
</tr>
   <?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId() && $_giftMessage = $this- 
 >helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_item- 
 >getGiftMessageId())): ?>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="3" class="item-extra">
    <table class="message-gift">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message') ?></h3>
                <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                    <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Updated default.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_order = $_item->getOrder();
?>
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
<?php $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>
<tr>
<td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>">
    <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
    <p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU') ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
    <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
        <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
            <dt><strong><em><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
            <dd>
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  nl2br($option['value']) ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
     <?php endif; ?>
     <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
     <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
        <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
     <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
 </td>

  <td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?></td>
  <td class="item-price"><?=  /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?></td>
 <td class="item-part"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $product- 
>getAlternatePartNumber(); ?></td>
 </tr>
   <?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId() && $_giftMessage = $this- 
 >helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_item- 
 >getGiftMessageId())): ?>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="item-extra">
    <table class="message-gift">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message') ?></h3>
                <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage- 
>getMessage()) ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: Where did you created this attribute? Also update your whole default.phtml code?

Comment: @SukumarGorai What do you mean where did you create this attribute? I added my entire default.phtml code.

Comment: @tjjen, did you try script in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You have used `$block->getAlternatePartNumber($_item)`, but if you print `$_item`you will not get your custom attribute here.

You need to load `$_item` and get custom attribute by following code:

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
<?php $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>

<td class="item-part"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $product->getAlternatePartNumber(); ?></td>
```

**Note:** Above code will show custom Attribute value, But Never use object manager directly to load model. You should use `Factories`

**Edit I**

There is no email configured on my local, So I have test above code using following script with name `test.php`:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$om = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

//here your logic start

$id = 1;

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);

echo $product->getAlternatePartNumber();
```

When I am hitting `http://localhost/magento2/test.php`, its giving me attribute value.

You need to debug what is not working and for that.

```
1. log product id
2. log attribute value
3. See all log for any error
```

Comment: I am a little confused. It seems like you are giving me code that would work, but telling me not to use it and do it a different way. Or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: You can use above code.

Comment: I updated the code with your code and still nothing. Did I place it in the wrong spots?

Comment: I did add the code in the original post so you could see.

Comment: what is the type of your AlternatePartNumber attribute ?

Comment: It is a text field

Comment: Please try with $product->getAttributeText('whatever_attribute_code'); instead of $product->getAlternatePartNumber();

Comment: Still getting a blank. This is what I added-<td class="item-part"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $product->getAttributeText('alternate_part_number'); ?></td>

Comment: did you check my updates ?